# unable to update value within a Javascript object literal, and then update the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've tried around 10 answers to other questions here but nothing seems to work. I've tried each and map and grep.

I want to change a value in an object literal and then update my list.

Here's the array:

```
goals = [
  {
    goalguid: "691473a7-acad-458e-bb27-96bac224205b",
    category: "personal",
    datecreated: "2013-10-20",
    startdate: "2013-10-28",
    enddate: "2013-11-26",
    goal: "go to store",
    icon: "cart",
    status: "completed",
    username: "jtmagee",
    userguid: "0c7270bd-38e8-4db2-ae92-244de019c543"
  }, {
    goalguid: "9e693231-e6d8-4ca9-b5c8-81ea7a80a36a",
    category: "personal",
    datecreated: "2013-10-20",
    startdate: "2013-10-27",
    enddate: "2013-11-27",
    goal: "Brush Teeth",
    icon: "doctor",
    status: "inprogress",
    username: "jtmagee",
    userguid: "0c7270bd-38e8-4db2-ae92-244de019c543"
  }, {
    goalguid: "8d23005d-f6f3-4589-bb85-a90510bccc21",
    category: "work",
    datecreated: "2013-10-20",
    startdate: "2013-10-26",
    enddate: "2013-11-28",
    goal: "Arrive on Time",
    icon: "alarm",
    status: "inprogress",
    username: "jtmagee",
    userguid: "0c7270bd-38e8-4db2-ae92-244de019c543"
  }, {
    goalguid: "ac879673-19eb-43f6-8b95-078d84552da0",
    category: "school",
    datecreated: "2013-10-20",
    startdate: "2013-10-24",
    enddate: "2013-11-29",
    goal: "Do Math Homework",
    icon: "book",
    status: "missed",
    username: "jtmagee",
    userguid: "0c7270bd-38e8-4db2-ae92-244de019c543"
  }
];
```

I'm keying off the goalguid gotten from the li that the user has clicked. I use the status key to change classes on the li.

Here's my jQuery that catches the click on a checkbox:

```
$(".goals").delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "click", function() {
  goalguid = $(this).parent().parent().data("goalguid");
  emailGoal = $(this).parent().data('goal');
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("inprogress missed").addClass("completed").prop("checked", true);
    updateStatus = 'completed';
    return updateTheGoal();
  } else {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("completed").addClass("inprogress").prop("checked", false);
    updateStatus = 'inprogress';
    return updateTheGoal();
  }
});
```

Here's what I can't get to work. Some attempts cleaned out the array completely, but most, including this, do  nothing except make my list flash. The displayGoalList function works fine for other uses.

```
updateTheGoal = function() {
  var goalList;
  $.each(goals, function() {
    if (goals.goalguid === goalguid) {
      return goals.status === updateStatus;
    }
  });
  goals = JSON.parse(localStorage["goals"]);
  goalList = $.grep(goals, function(e) {
    return e.userguid === userguid;
  });
  localStorage.setItem(userguid + "Goals", JSON.stringify(goalList));
  logSummary();
  return displayMyGoalList();
};
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you also add html that you use? I would try to reproduce problem and then try to find out solution. Could be just a scratch of it ofc. Just to reproduce that and check in jsfiddle for example ;)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but your `each` literally does nothing.  It contains an `if` and a return statement which is never used (it actually just potentially breaks the loop).  On top of that you're checking properties on the array, not the elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(goals, function() {
    if (goals.goalguid === goalguid) {
      return goals.status === updateStatus;
    }
});
```

You are checking `goals.goalguid` and setting `goals.status`.  This is wrong.  `goals` is an array.  Your intent is to check each element in the array.  Then you aren't actually doing anything with your return.  `return` within `each` simply breaks the loop or continues it (depending on return value).  I think you meant to assign it.  Try this:

```
$.each(goals, function(i, el) {
    if (el.goalguid === goalguid) {
        el.status = updateStatus;
        return false; // break the each
    }
});
```

Also, remove this bit that will replace any change made by your `each` with whatever is stored in local storage:

```
goals = JSON.parse(localStorage["goals"]);
```

Comment: Your answer worked perfect. The note about the JSON.parse made me realize that's where my setItem needed to be. Also, an obvious beginner question: so the i is to provide a counter for the each, and the el is the placeholder for the items in the array that it's counting through? Finally, not sure on protocol: should I update the question with the code as it worked for me so future readers can see your solution integrated into it? Thanks very much @james-montagne

Comment: Uh-oh. Now I can only click on one item in my list. I can't uncheck it or check any other items.

Comment: Yep, this solution only works once. It only changes and updates the object on the first click. Nothing after that. I've tried adding .checkboxradio("refresh") at the end of the class change and that returns the boxes and class change, but then I lose the updating of the object.

Comment: I don't see a reason this would only work once.  If you can re-create the issue in http://jsfiddle.net I could probably find the issue.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me James. This is my first attempt at creating a fiddle, so it's kinda messy. The CSS is all screwed up, but if you make the results window wide you'll be able to read it. Click the Mary Jones student. Uncheck that first Completed checkbox. If you have devtools open to resources/localstorage, you'll see the status change based on the code you gave me. But now the checkboxes are dead.

Comment: Sorry if I'm just missing it somehow, but I don't think you added the link to the fiddle.

Comment: Once you reload the table your `goalguid` is undefined because the data attribute is not added.  You'll need to debug the code that builds the table and find out why.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to track it down.